# Trying to update a 3D graphs coordinates with matplotlib

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

I have a function that will graph a 3D sphere with matplotlib in tkinter. However, every successive time I call the function the performance when orbiting the sphere drops. Also the graph only updates after I try to orbit the sphere.

**self.A** is a variable that adjusts the size of the sphere.

My function:

```
def draw_fig(self):

        self.ax = Axes3D(self.fig)

        u = numpy.linspace(0, 2 * numpy.pi, 100)
        v = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi, 100)
        x = self.A * numpy.outer(numpy.cos(u), numpy.sin(v))
        y = self.A * numpy.outer(numpy.sin(u), numpy.sin(v))
        z = self.A * numpy.outer(numpy.ones(numpy.size(u)), numpy.cos(v))

        t = self.ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4,color='lightblue',linewidth=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not regenerate each time all the data, but just modify your existing one.

Edit: Just move out of the calling draw_fig the axes building code

```
def __init__...
     u = numpy.linspace(0, 2 * numpy.pi, 100)
     v = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi, 100)
     self.x = A * numpy.outer(numpy.cos(u), numpy.sin(v))
     self.y = A * numpy.outer(numpy.sin(u), numpy.sin(v))
     self.z = A * numpy.outer(numpy.ones(numpy.size(u)), numpy.cos(v))
     self.ax = Axes3D(self.fig)

def draw_fig(self):

        t = self.ax.plot_surface(self.x, self.y, self.z,  rstride=4, cstride=4,color='lightblue',linewidth=0)
```

Comment: How would I impliment this? Also self.A is an integer that can either be 10 or 5.